# Google sheet: SUMIF with relative (not fixed) sum range?

Tags: google-sheets

I have my data organised in a NxN table with coupled columns {quantity,code} (see image below).

I'm looking for a function able to calculate total quantity by code.

I've tried with [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en), but it seems to work only with a fixed sum range, whilst I need a RELATIVE sum range.

Can you address me to the right solution?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this should work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(A2:G4*(B2:H4=A7)*(A1:G1="quantity")))
```

just using multiplication of booleans to get at the correct values is sometimes simpler.

Comment: Yes it works! You have opened new scenarios in my mind about the usage of arrayformula!